# How to prompt a user for input until the input is valid in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to make a program to prompt a user for input until they enter a number within a specific range.

What is the best approach to make sure the code does not error out when I enter a letter, a symbol, or a number outside of the specified range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In alternative to [`parse`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/numbers/#Base.parse), you can use [`tryparse`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/numbers/#Base.tryparse):

> `tryparse(type, str; base)`
>
> Like `parse`, but returns either a value of the requested type, or
>   `nothing` if the string does not contain a valid number.

The advantage over `parse` is that you can have a cleaner error handling without resorting to [`try`/`catch`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#The-try/catch-statement-1), which would hide all exceptions raised within the block.

For example you can do:

```
while true
    print("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 5: ")
    input = readline(stdin)
    value = tryparse(Int, input)
    if value !== nothing && 1 <= value <= 5
        println("You entered $(input)")
        break
    else
        @warn "Enter a whole number between 1 and 5"
    end
end
```

Sample run:

```
Please enter a whole number between 1 and 5: 42
┌ Warning: Enter a whole number between 1 and 5
└ @ Main myscript.jl:9
Please enter a whole number between 1 and 5: abcde
┌ Warning: Enter a whole number between 1 and 5
└ @ Main myscript.jl:9
Please enter a whole number between 1 and 5: 3
You entered 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way to achieve this sort of thing:

```
while true
    print("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 5: ")
    input = readline(stdin)
    try
        if parse(Int, input) <= 5 || parse(Int, input) >= 1
            print("You entered $(input)")
            break
        end
    catch
        @warn "Enter a whole number between 1 and 5"
    end
end
```

Sample Run:

```
Please enter a whole number between 1 and 5: 2
You entered 2
```

[See this link for how to parse the user input into an int.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/numbers/#Base.parse)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for pointing that out. Feel free to post an alternative solution if you think it looks simpler.